# Unable to run NavigationActions.reset() in react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to clear the navigation stack using the following code

**Signup.js**

```
const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
      index: 0,
      actions: [
        NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Portal'})
      ]
    })
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
```

but getting the following error when running.

> Cannot redefine property: __hooks

The routeName is registered in my initial stack navigator and the resetAction code is in the page before the Portal page.

So the screen progression is Signup -> Portal

Sometimes I get a

> attempting to change value of a readonly property

error instead of the cannot redefine property. This problem has me scratching my head for a few days.. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this will defienty help you

```
 const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Portal'})
  ],
 key:null
})
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Ashutosh's solution should have worked but I was still getting the same error. After further digging I found that I had an open feathersjs connection in my previous screens that was not closed.

When I took out the connections the reset action worked. Next step will be to add in logic to close the connections when not used.

Thanks alot :)